# How to make sumoselect dropdown wider

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, sumoselect.js

This is what my dropdown for sumoselect looks like:

[image]

I would like the dropdown to be wider but I haven't been able to figure out how to affect it. Anyone know what css to override or how to do it?

For reference: https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect

Tried editing the CSS in the inspector; no luck.

[image]

Comment: Where is your problem? Just adapt the css: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/18o9wm57/). You can use your browser console to inspect elements and see the applied CSS-rules.

Comment: That works for non-sumoselect; I tried added a width, but it gets ignored.

Comment: Actually, trying to set the width seems to remove the scrollbar, so that's not great. This really is a 'sumoselect' specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work by changing the width in the sumoselect.css

FROM:

.SumoSelect{width: 200px;}

TO:

.SumoSelect{width: inherit;} 
Then wrapped each instance with the desired width (if necessary):

.
.
.

Comment: Thanks, that probably works, but I'm not using sumo-select anymore so can't verify.

Comment: I can confirm this is working. I just tried it. In case someone is still interested in this.